# Is there any limitation on the number of applications that can be signed with one certificate?

Tags: certificate, code-signing

I bought a code signing certificate (in my name) for windows and I signed 2 apps with it (the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of my app), both apps seems to be signed properly but I don't know if each certificate should be used for one app or can be used for multiple ones? could it cause any problems? thanks

Comment: I think the signature will work for all apps as publishers release many apps with the same certificate.

Comment: Only as many Angels as can dance on the head of a pin.  No, there should not be any limit, and it would be quite difficult to enforce one even if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you have adopted code Signing Certificate of any certificate Authority, there is no limit to sign Application, Software or Documents.

You are allowed to sign any number of Apps, Software & documents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit.
It is worth noting that in most cases, the purpose of a signing certificate is not to certify the contents itself (in this case, the app), but its origins. Multiple apps signed with the same certificate would point to the fact that they're originating from the same source.